# Restricted shell for managing files and git repositories

Tags: linux, security

Think about a web hosting company that wants to let users manage files and git repositories via ssh. This includes:

- secure copy (scp)
- creating, copying, moving/renaming and deleting files
- executing a narrow subset of commands for source control and text editing (git, vim, nano)

We would like to implement that and looked into the following options:

- [rssh](http://www.pizzashack.org/rssh/)
- [scponly](https://github.com/scponly/scponly/wiki)

These would allow for the scp part, but using git doesn't seem to be possible. There is a patch in [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rssh/+bug/734530), but I'm not sure what to make of it. There is [git-shell](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-shell.html), too, but it doesn't seem to allow editors. Maybe vim is even too much, because it could be used to execute more code, so we could drop that (vim, or text editors completely, if must be) if it is too much.

We basically want to lock down the shell, so the user can manage (and edit) files and git repositories, but the user should not be able to execute any other programs on the system. The biggest problem would be abuse of network and computing resources, but using the system as a proxy too. You name it. Is there a way to do this or do we maybe even have the wrong approach on this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two complementary ways to implement this:

### Granting users permissions to use `git` repositories remotely

Use `gitolite3` to provide a hub-live repositories schema (this is described in detail [here](http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/)), that basically requires you to have a `bare` repository (a **hub** repo) to let your users to push/pull from and a checked-out version of the same repo (a **live** repo) located in the appropriate path, say `/srv/www/html`, for example.

I like to use `gitolite3` to handle the **hub** repo, but that is not a requirement, though it's rather convenient to have [fine-grained access control bound to your LDAP of choice](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/contrib/utils/ipa_groups.pl) if needs be. `gitolite3` can provide fine-grained control down to the branch level.

It is also a good practice to limit the capabilities of the `gitolite3` user via `sudo`, and handle the hooks by means of `sudo` calls. This is a working example using `gitolite3` hooks (feel free to adapt them -or enhance/fix them- to suit your needs):

- The relevant content of the `/etc/sudoers` or `/etc/sudoers.d/gitolite3` would be something along the lines of:

  ```
  Cmnd_Alias        GITOLITE_CMDS = /usr/bin/git, /bin/chown, /bin/find, /usr/bin/xargs, /bin/chmod, /sbin/restorecon, /usr/local/sbin/publisher-hub2live
  Cmnd_Alias GITOLITE_APACHE_CMDS = /usr/sbin/apachectl graceful
  Defaults:gitolite3 !requiretty
  Defaults:gitolite3 lecture=never
  gitolite3                ALL = (root)NOPASSWD: GITOLITE_CMDS
  gitolite3       APACHE_HOSTS = (root)NOPASSWD: GITOLITE_APACHE_CMDS
  ```
- **hub** repo `post-update` hook:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh

  echo "****"
  echo "**** Calling publisher-hub2live script [Hub's post-update hook]"
  echo "****"

  sudo /usr/local/sbin/publisher-hub2live "/srv/www/html" "root:apache" "2750" "640"

  exit 0
  ```
- `publisher-hub2live` script:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh

  echo "****"
  echo "**** Pulling changes into Live [publisher-hub2live]"
  echo "****"

  cd "$1" || exit
  umask 0022
  unset GIT_DIR
  /usr/bin/git pull hub master

  # custom actions here
  # e.g call grunt tasks
  /bin/chown -R "$2" "$1"
  /bin/find "$1" -type d -exec chmod "$3" {} +
  /bin/find "$1" -type f -exec chmod "$4" {} +
  /bin/chmod u+x "$1"/.git/hooks/post-commit
  /sbin/restorecon -R -v "$1"
  exec /usr/bin/git update-server-info

  exit 0
  ```

### Limiting the ability to execute non-authorized commands in a login shell

What you'd need to implement is a reproducible, auditable method of limiting the ability of the user to perform actions other than the strictly allowed.

It is not required but it helps if you have your users registered in LDAP, and you have already deployed the mechanisms to perform LDAP authentication, be it by means of a PAM module, or using freeIPA and `sssd`.

To implement this scenario, what I currently do is the following (be aware that this kind of restrictions requires that several conditions are met, otherwise the restriction can be easily circumvented):

- The users do not belong to the `wheel` group, the only one authorized to use `su` (enforced via PAM). Usually, a non-LDAP user (`sysadm`) exists to allow trusted administrators performing actions in cases of disaster recovery or LDAP unavailability.
- The users are given a properly secured `rbash` with a read-only PATH pointing to a private `~/bin`, this `~/bin/` directory contains links to all allowed commands, for example:

  ```
  $ ll ~/bin
  total 0
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 14 Sep 17 08:58 clear -> /usr/bin/clear*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud  7 Sep 17 08:58 df -> /bin/df*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 10 Sep 17 08:58 egrep -> /bin/egrep*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud  8 Sep 17 08:58 env -> /bin/env*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 10 Sep 17 08:58 fgrep -> /bin/fgrep*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 14 Sep 17 08:58 git -> /usr/bin/git*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud  9 Sep 17 08:58 grep -> /bin/grep*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 10 Sep 17 08:58 rview -> /bin/rview*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 13 Sep 17 08:58 sudo -> /usr/bin/sudo*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 17 Sep 17 08:58 sudoedit -> /usr/bin/sudoedit*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 13 Sep 17 08:58 tail -> /usr/bin/tail*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 11 Sep 17 08:58 wc -> /usr/bin/wc*
  ```
- the users are given a restricted, read-only environment (think of stuff like `LESSSECURE`, `TMOUT`, `HISTFILE` variables). This is to avoid `shell` escapes from commands like `less` and ensure auditability.
- the only allowed editor is`rvim`, for the same reason. Users can only execute `sudoedit`, whic in configured to run `rvim` in the `sudo` configuration:

  ```
  Defaults editor=/usr/bin/rvim
  ```
- if MAC restrictions are in place (the specific GNU/Linux distribution you are using has SELinux enabled), the users are mapped to the SELinux user `staff_u` and given rights to execute commands as other user as required via `sudo`. The specific `sudorules` allowed need to be carefully reviewed to prevent the user from circumventing these limitations, and can also be deployed in your existing LDAP infrastructure (this is one of freeIPA features).
- the users' `/home`, `/tmp` and possibly `/var/tmp` are polyinstantiated via `/etc/security/namespace.conf`:

  ```
  /tmp       /tmp/.inst/tmp.inst-$USER-     tmpdir:create   root
  /var/tmp   /tmp/.inst/var-tmp.inst-$USER- tmpdir:create   root
  $HOME      $HOME/$USER.inst/              tmpdir:create   root
  ```

  Polyinstantiation of directories is not a new feature, it has been available for quite a long time now. As a reference, see [this article from 2006](http://www.coker.com.au/selinux/talks/sage-2006/PolyInstantiatedDirectories.html). As a matter of fact, a lot of modules already use `pam_namespace` by default, but the default configuration at `/etc/security/namespace.conf` does not enable polyinstantiation.
  Also, `/etc/security/namespace.init` should make all skeletal files read-only for the users and owned by `root`.

This way you can choose whether the users can execute any command on their own behalf (via a link in the private `~/bin` directory, provisioned via `/etc/skel`, as explained above), on behalf of other user (via `sudo`) or none at all.